# BrokenPipe Error at process.StandartInput() on .NetCore in Ubuntu 18

Tags: c#, .net-core, ubuntu-18.04

There is the utility for migrating from Sqlite to PostgreSQL on .Net Core 2.0. On Ubuntu 18 with `process.StandartInput()`, a BrokenPipe error occurs,on Ubuntu 16 everythings works, what could be the problem? On the pictures,the utility code and error

[image]

```
System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. (Broken pipe) ---> 
System.IO.IOException: Broken pipe at System.IO.FileStream.WriteNative(Byte[] array, Int32 offset, Int32 count) 
at System.IO.FileStream.FlushWriteBuffer() 
at System.IO.FileStream.Dispose(Boolean disposing) 
at System.IO.Stream.Close() at System.IO.StreamWriter.Dispose(Boolean disposing)
at System.IO.TextWriter.Dispose() at SQLiteToPostgre.Program.<ExecuteSqliteCmd
```

Comment: Please always share the code as text and not image.

Comment: System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. (Broken pipe) ---> Syste                                                                                        m.IO.IOException: Broken pipe
   at System.IO.FileStream.WriteNative(Byte[] array, Int32 offset, Int32 count)
   at System.IO.FileStream.FlushWriteBuffer()
   at System.IO.FileStream.Dispose(Boolean disposing)
   at System.IO.Stream.Close()
   at System.IO.StreamWriter.Dispose(Boolean disposing)
   at System.IO.TextWriter.Dispose()
   at SQLiteToPostgre.Program.<ExecuteSqliteCmd

Comment: Please read this - https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question. It will help you to understand why code as image is bad.